# How to use .animate javascript in Safari ? Getting undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to animate multiples leafs randomly. Here's my code :

```
var leafs = document.querySelectorAll(".leaf");

leafs.forEach(function(leaf) {

        var angle = parseInt(leaf.getAttribute("data-angle")),
            posY = parseInt(leaf.getAttribute("data-top")),
            posX = parseInt(leaf.getAttribute("data-left")),
            directionX = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1,
            directionY = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1,
            newposX = directionX * Math.round(Math.random()*10) + posX,
            newposY = directionY * Math.round(Math.random()*10) + posY,
            angleRotation = Math.round(Math.random()*20) + angle;
            //keyframe = {transform: ['translate3d(' + posX + 'px,' + posY + 'px, 0px) rotate(' + angle + 'deg)', 'translate3d(' + newposX + ',' + newposY + ', 0px) rotate(' + angleRotation + ')']};

        console.log(leaf);

        leaf.animate([
            {
             transform: 'translate3d(' + posX + 'px,' + posY + 'px, 0px) rotate(' + angle + 'deg) '
            },
            {
             transform: 'translate3d(' + newposX + 'px,' + newposY + 'px, 0px) rotate(' + angleRotation + 'deg)'
            }
        ], {
            iterations: Infinity,
            direction: 'alternate',
            easing: 'ease-in-out',
            duration: 3000
        });
    });
```

In firefox & chrome it's working fine. In safari I got the following error I don't know how to deal with it. I'm using **vanilla** javascript.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...leaf.animate...')
```

**UPDATE**

Turns out I either need a polyfill or Jquery.

PolyFill can be found here : [web-animations-js](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js)

Comment: There is no browser support. Check mdn for a polyfill (if one exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`web-animations-js`](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js), the w3 polyfill provided by Google. It's a bit dated but works for most Web Animations API features on at least the top 99% of browsers.